# UIButtons added to a container view stopped working

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I have added a transparent view to my main view and placed previously working UIButtons in this. The reason I have a transparent view is for autolayout purposes. The buttons have now stopped working though. Do they need to be connected to the container view or something to work? If I connect them to the container view then surely I am going to have to write a delegate and protocol to get them communicating with the view controller. Any advice on this would be really appreciated!

Comment: Check "User Interaction" is enabled for the container

Comment: What other troubleshooting have you tried? Are the buttons connected to the actions? Can you describe your view hierarchy?

Comment: Is the transparent view filling your main view?  If not, make sure the buttons exist within the bounds of the transparent view, otherwise the transparent view won't relay touch events to the buttons. I recently put a button in a subview but placed it so that it wasn't within the subview bounds and had a similar issue.

Comment: The transparent view doesn't fill the whole subview no. I'll take a look.

Comment: @user2320861 yes the buttons are well within the bounds. No relaying anything though..

Comment: How are you checking that the buttons are within the bounds? Try setting the clipsToBounds property to YES for your transparent view (or check the "clip subviews" box in IB), and see if the buttons still appear.

Comment: I checked the box and the buttons vanish completely.

Comment: I tried resizing the container view, moving the buttons around and resizing them. They only work when they aren't sitting in the container. Am I going to have to write a protocol ?

Comment: If your buttons are being clipped (disappearing) then they're not in the bounds of their parent.

Comment: Is the parent view of the buttons handling touch events?

Comment: @user2320861 my main view controller is handling the touch events. I have a view controller. In the view controller I have the transparent container view. In that container view sit the buttons and they are connected to the main view controller.

Comment: Are you using touchesBegan:WithEvent: in your main view controller? If so, just for fun comment out the touch handling methods and see what happens